# Spring boot application: CommandLine runner exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on an application using spring data jpa. I am streaming ~1000000 fields from a Mysql database that work fine inside a Junit test container. But when I run the same logical code with the CommandLineRunner, the application hangs after returning ~10,000 fields with the following stacktrace:

```
07 Mar 2017 10:49:24  INFO MysqlApplication - Field number: 12172
2017-03-07 10:49:58.340 ERROR 22072 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.cohort.alive.data.facade.mysql.MysqlApplication.main(MysqlApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1045) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5202) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:696) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadSingleRow(Loader.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.prepareCurrentRow(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl.next(ScrollableResultsImpl.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider$HibernateScrollableResultsIterator.hasNext(PersistenceProvider.java:454) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.cohort.alive.data.facade.mysql.MysqlApplication.run(MysqlApplication.java:35) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted

2017-03-07 10:49:58.343  INFO 22072 --- [  restartedMain] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/N:/git/clinical-pipeline/cognitive-nlu/target/classes/]
2017-03-07 10:49:58.343  INFO 22072 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2017-03-07 10:49:58.343  INFO 22072 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@10086c99: startup date [Tue Mar 07 10:49:16 PST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-07 10:49:58.350  INFO 22072 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-03-07 10:49:58.352  INFO 22072 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I am stumped and cannot figure it out. Really appreciate if someone can giving me any pointers

EDIT (MysqlApplication.java)

```
public class MysqlApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MysqlApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    BusinessRepository businessRepository;

    final static private Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("MysqlApplication");

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.info("Streaming All....");
         Stream<business> concepts = businessRepository.streamAll();
         int [] j ={0};
         concepts.forEach(i -> {
             LOGGER.info("Field Number: "j[0]++");
     }
}
```

EDIT 2: I think I solved the problem by annotating the application class with transactional. Although I do not really understand why that makes a difference. Would be great if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Can you post your MysqlApplication class code?

Comment: Your Hibernate mapping appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @Compass it's working fine inside the Junit Test. So I think the hibernate mapping should be correct. Also if you notice it returned me 12172 fields before hanging up.

Comment: @artemisian Just edited, with the application code added

Comment: If you test code is exactly the same as your MysqlApplication code, and your test class runs without any issues then your problem is in the configuration used. Look for the differences

Comment: There is no difference. I checked for all that. Also it streams a good number of fields (12172 in this run) before hanging up. That number changes everytime i run it but usually in a similar range. I think the problem is with the CommandLineRunner because that's what I am not using in my test class

Comment: Your exception says `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null` from a Hibernate source.